# How to record rtsp stream to file in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtsp

I need to record a rtsp video stream to file in python, I want to stop the recording at anytime depending on the situation.  I used subprocess to interact with ffmpeg command line, but it breaks sometimes, the video keep recording, resulting in a huge file.

Is there any good way to dump a rtsp video stream to file, with the capability that you can stop the recording anytime after you start recording?

Any help is much appreciated.

ADDED:

Preferably the similar API as the PiCamera like so:

```
import picamera
from time import sleep

camera = picamera.PiCamera()

camera.start_recording('video.h264')
sleep(5)
camera.stop_recording()
```

But the only difference is that the source of video is the IP camera.